# active record - grouping with joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to be able to output something like the following:

```
Name     Car Type 1     Car Type 2     Car Type 3
Dave     1                    3          6
Mike     5                    2          8
```

Any advice on achieving this with active record? **(rails 3.1)**

Models:

```
class Person
#name
 has_many :sales
end

class Sales
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :car
end

class Cars
 #type, id, name
    has_many :sales
end
```

Comment: what version of rails are you using? the answer might differ a lot depending on the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a no-SQL solution:

```
sales = Sale.includes( :person, :car ).all # or whatever you want to filter
sales_by_person = sales.group_by( :person )

grouped_sales = {}

sales_by_person.each do |person,sales|
  grouped_sales[person] = sales.group_by(:car).map { |car,car_sales| [ car, car_sales.size ] }
end

puts grouped_sales.inspect
```